# Shutdown command no longer broadcasts messages

Tags: linux, command-line, shutdown

The shutdown command has stopped broadcasting messages like this:

```
luzar@ubuntu:~$ sudo shutdown -h -P +3 Please save your work now!

Broadcast message from luzar@ubuntu
        (/dev/pts/0) at 11:57 ...

The system is going down for power off in 3 minutes!
```

Why has this happened? How can I fix it?

Comment: When you run `who`, does it show entries for your terminal windows? That list (the utmp database) is where `shutdown` looks for terminals to notify.

Comment: Run `mesg y` at the terminal you're expecting the message - `mesg` is access control for programs like `wall` (which I think most shutdown scripts use), and you may have it set to view messages.